# Google chrome frame messes up printing MathML

Tags: printing, cross-browser, mathjax, mathml, google-chrome-frame

I use [Mathjax](http://www.mathjax.org/) to render some formulas on a site and everything works fine untill I try to print them.

In IE, FF, Chrome everything works fine and the page is printed. But if I have Google Chrome Frame installed in IE it will mess up the formula:

```
"9a + 9 = 8a + 3" turns in to "7: ) 7 ; 6: ) 1".
```

The problem is that the page for printing is opened in a new window and this new page doesn't use Chrome Frame. If I select the URL and hit <kbd>enter</kbd>, the page is rendered without the MathML tags and everything works fine.

Does anyone have any ideas of what this could be? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The [print preview](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=95568) used Chrome emulation at some point, but it was buggy and subsequently removed. The print preview and print output both use the native IE engine, which can render MathML using a combination of  alternatives:

- [MathPlayer ActiveX Plugin](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb250508)
- [MathML Stylesheets](http://www.w3.org/Math/XSL/)
- [Presentation MathML Stylesheet](http://www.nag.co.uk/numeric/FL/nagdoc_fl22/xhtml/styles/pmathml.xsl)
- [Content MathML Stylesheet](http://www.dcarlisle.demon.co.uk/omml2mml/xhtml-mathml.xsl)

The stylesheets require the [XHTML+XML stylesheet](http://www.echoofeden.com/digest/mit/2007/03/06/ie-xhtml-bug/) to render properly.

**References**

- [Chrome Frame Troubleshooting - The Chromium Projects](https://www.chromium.org/developers/diagnostics/gcf_troubleshooting)
- [Debugging NACL Apps with Eclipse CDT](https://www.chromium.org/nativeclient/how-tos/debugging-documentation/debugging-with-debug-stub-recommended/debugging-nacl-apps-in-eclipse-cdt)